# Tensorflow: Reading Many Images (or any file) from a list of zip/tar files

Tags: tensorflow, zip

I have a dataset of many zip files, and each zip file contains many images. I would like to setup a tensorflow read pipeline that opens each zip file, and extracts each image within the zip file as separate record. I've seen [guides on how to open up multiple image files](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f), but not how to open images within a zip. How would I do this?

*Note: I'm using zip, but this similarly applies to tar files.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow currently does not provide a decoder for zip or tar files.

You can - of course - read zip or tars using a [WholeFileReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/WholeFileReader). For unzipping/untaring you would have to roll your own decoder, though. You can find a Quickstart on how to do that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/new_data_formats#writing_an_op_for_a_record_format).

Alternatively you can create a custom Reader. A Quickstart for doing that is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/new_data_formats#writing_a_reader_for_a_file_format).